# how correctly configure dpkg in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y -f && \
    wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs npm && \
    npm install -g forever

WORKDIR /app
COPY start.js .

CMD ["forever", "start", "-s", "start.js"]
```

and I'm getting this problem while executing Docker build

```
Unpacking wkhtmltox (1:0.12.5-1.bionic) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:
 wkhtmltox depends on fontconfig; however:
  Package fontconfig is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libfreetype6; however:
  Package libfreetype6 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libjpeg-turbo8; however:
  Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libpng16-16; however:
  Package libpng16-16 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libx11-6; however:
  Package libx11-6 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libxcb1; however:
  Package libxcb1 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libxext6; however:
  Package libxext6 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on libxrender1; however:
  Package libxrender1 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-75dpi; however:
  Package xfonts-75dpi is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-base; however:
  Package xfonts-base is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wkhtmltox (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wkhtmltox
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y wget &&     wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb &&     dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb &&     apt install -y -f &&     wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb &&     apt install -y ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb &&     apt-get clean &&     rm wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb &&     apt-get install -y nodejs npm &&     npm install -g forever' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I'm trying to build Docker image, but because of this, I'm stuck I have tried so many solution to resolve this problem, Please can anyone help me to resolve this problem

Comment: In a nutshell `apt install ...` resolves all dependencies for a given package, `dpkg -i ...` does not. You get very clear error messages here (and can moreover debug it interactively too) so ensure the packages needed by `wkhtmltox` are in fact installed.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Dirk,

Please put line below:

```
apt-get install -y fontconfig libfreetype6 libjpeg-turbo8 libpng16-16 libx11-6 libxcb1 libxext6 libxrender1 xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base
```

just after following line:

```
apt-get install -y wget && \
```

This works on my setup (Even though takes a while to install but workable)

Hope this helps, Thanks.